# Can a shapefile contains shapes who are overlaps with each other?

Tags: dictionary, buffer, gis, shapefile

When I want to buffer a shapefile to a new one, I have a question as the following image indicated. I'm new to GeoProcessing, please guild me to the right way.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question in the title is "Yes", shapefiles can contain overlapping polygons.

But then your picture is asking something else...

On the left, you show the case where you save three features to the shapefile, one for each of your buffer regions. In this case, each feature is the buffer of a specific feature in your input shapefile.

On the right, you've saved a single feature. This is the area that is the union of the buffers.

Which one you want depends on the question you are asking - on the left you'll be able to identify points within a distance of a given input feature, on the right all you can say about a point is whether it is within a distance of any of the input features.

Which one you get when you do the buffer depends on the software you are using. It might have an option for returning individual buffers like on the left or merging them all like on the right.

In R, using rgeos and gBuffer, you use gBuffer(shapes, buffer, byid=TRUE) to get individual buffers like on the left (one for each 'id'). Otherwise (byid=FALSE) you get one merged buffer polygon like on the right.